# Error while running ruby server on text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I am new to ruby on rail i have installed ruby on my system globally  ruby -v command is working fine on my CMD but when i run it from other command prompt it give me not found error now i tried running it on my visual Code terminal and it is saying

```
"rails : The term 'rails' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again."
```

i need help with this please anyone

Comment: Have you installed the rails gem ?

Answer (score 3):

On a new ruby on rails project run this to install your dependencies

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```